# C# Regex: parse input string as regex

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am implementing full text search for mongodb on premise installations.
I want to have query terms to be separated by white spaces and allow for wildcards (and only wildcards).
I already managed to do the splitting and to query a text index using `$regex`.

But now I have trouble to  figure out a clean way to parse possible terms.

```
Hannah -> $regex: "Hannah"
Hanna* -> $regex: "\\QHanna\\E.*" (treat every char before '*' as literal and allow 0-n chars afterwards)
*Ha*na* -> $regex: ".*\\QHa\\E.*\\Qna\\E.*"
```

Splitting terms by `new Regex("\\*")` came to mind but there is also at least one example where my algorithm fails or would be too complicated to understand.
Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Update:
I finally managed to transform my search terms like this:

```
["term1","t*e*m*","*t*"]
.Select(
    remainingTerm =>
        {
            // now also allow multiple wildcards by encoding it for mongodb
            var wildCardPattern = new Regex("[^*]*\\*");
            if (!wildCardPattern.IsMatch(remainingTerm))
            {
                return Builders<Batch>.Filter.Regex(
                    batch => batch.SearchableTerms,
                    new BsonRegularExpression($"^\\Q{remainingTerm}\\E$"));
            }

            // map '*' to '.*' and treat remaining chars as literal (only wildcards are supported)
            remainingTerm = wildCardPattern.Replace(
                remainingTerm,
                match =>
                    {
                        // map '*' to '.*' and treat remaining chars as literal
                        if (match.Value == "*")
                        {
                            return ".*";
                        }

                        var result = $"\\Q{match.Value.Substring(0, match.Value.Length - 1)}\\E.*";
                        return result;
                    }
            );

            return Builders<Batch>.Filter.Regex(
                batch => batch.SearchableTerms,
            new BsonRegularExpression($"^{remainingTerm}$"));
        }));
```

Comment: .NET regex does not support `\Q` and `\E`, when someone uses it, the solution is most likely to be `Regex.Escape(word)`

Comment: $regex is  running on mongodb server which does understand that expression.